# Change nexus 8 brake

Tags: shimano, disc-brake, rear-wheel

I bought a Shimano Nexus 8 IGH with shimano nexave, but I would like change it to disc brake.

Is it possible install a rotor disc brake adaptor? Will it work?

Comment: Did you found an proper adapter?

Comment: I think they're completely different versions of the hub - you would need to replace the hub to get disk rotor mounts.

Comment: @Criggie yes, hub housing is different but I've found adaptor disc-> roller for nuVinci hub. It sounds incredible to me, but still cannot rule out that opposite adapter doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2):

When you are braking you are putting quite some load on the frame where the brakes are installed. (Newton's 3rd principle of dynamics: to each action corresponds an equal reaction with same intensity and opposite direction)

If the frame is not designed for this, you are aiming for disaster.

So, if the fork was not designed to have disc brakes installed, don't do it.

Comment: Thanks @L.Dutch for your help and advise. i thought with disc brake adaptor for frame and rotor could work like the same homemade low-riders i saw around the internet, but yes, you are right about the Newton's 3rd principle, i got you. i will follow your advise. Thank you

Comment: @Pypoka The home-made low-riders are designed to be ridden at low speed, or not at all. They use all sorts of horrible features, like radial spokes on the rear wheel. *Do not* use them as models.